# Escritura automática en python

Tags: python

Si tengo un número x y quiero que se escriba un * x veces(entre comillas) de forma automática, pero dentro de una sola variable, osea:

```py
a="***....hasta el x"
```

¿como lo hago?, ¿existe un comando para eso?

Comment: `x = 100` `a = "*" * x` `print(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más canónico es pensar en un bucle. Considere que usted tiene `x`, que representa el número de veces que desea que un determinado suceso ocurra; y luego `a`, que sería la cadena de texto que ir incrementando. Así pues:

```py
a = "" 
for _ in range(x):
    a += "*"
```

Python le permite conseguir lo anterior a través de diversas expresiones a menudo más compactas, como la que le plantea [@eyllanesc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22539/eyllanesc) en su comentario. Incluso podría emplear una compresión de lista: `str(''.join(["*" for _ in range(x)]))`. El principio es siempre el mismo.